# Auto complete in c [Codemirror]

Tags: javascript, c, autocomplete, codemirror

You can see this being used to autocomplete local JavaScript variables in http://codemirror.net/2/demo/complete.html
But,How i use this autocomplete in c language?

How i edit this code?
http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.js

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? You have to examine the code and figure out how it works. This might take time, but there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about editing the script to auto-complete C in the browser?

First you need to identify the where local variables in C are defined. You're looking for keywords like `int float long` or patterns like `type_name identifier_1 = value, identifier_2;`

The next thing you need to do is identify the function parameters. The pattern you're looking for is

```
return_type function_name(parm1, param2){
    // current code
}
```

Last you need to include constants created with `#define` and variables defined in file scope (C) or global scope (C++).

```
type_name identifier = value;
#define constant value

// Outside of any sort of scope

/* something  */{

}
```

It would be difficult to just edit the script that works on JavaScript because the two languages behave differently and have different rules. If you need some help of the ways to parse the data from C and other languages using JavaScript you might look into [google-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) which is a syntax highlighting script.

Good luck.